# Listbox.Contains with "Like" operator

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox on a winform with a couple of hundreds items. I would like to remove all those items that has the word "color" in it.

For example, here a some of the items in my listbox:

```
[0]Weight
[1]Height
[2]Eye Color
[3]Hair Color
[4]Discoloration
[5]Type
```

So, `[2] [3] [4]` will be removed from this listbox. (Case insensitive)

```
if (listbox.Items.Contains(//like %color%)
//remove items
```

My code so far:

```
//From multiple sources
foreach (string line in sometextfiles)
{
    lstNames.Items.Add(line)
}

foreach (string line in othertextfiles)
{
    if (!lstNames.Items.Contains(line))
    lstNames.Items.Add(line)
}

foreach (string line in moretextfiles)
{
    if (!lstNames.Items.Contains(line))
    lstNames.Items.Add(line)
}

foreach (string line in evenmoretextfiles)
{
    if (!lstNames.Items.Contains(line))
    lstNames.Items.Add(line)
}

//Finally I want to remove unwanted items
var query = (from x in lstNames.Items
                     where x.Contains("color")
                     select x);
```

Comment: I tried some LINQ query someting like `.Where(x => x.Contains("/color/"))` but it said LINQ query cannot be implemented on listbox

Comment: so do the linq on Listbox.items

Comment: @Delta I did, and I got an error message saying `Error 1 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.  'Where' not found.  `

Comment: Please show the complete code fragment so we can see clearly what you've tried, all in one place. Also, which versions of Visual Studio and .NET are you using?

Comment: What Grant Winney said ...we cannot help if you don't _post what you have tried_.

Comment: you will need to convert the items to the items source type then get the string part of the type. or try .ToString().Contains. but that is really a shot in the dark that tostring will work correctly

Comment: @ClickRick Please view codes above

Comment: Why not filter out the "color" strings before even adding them in the first place (in your initial line additions from the multiple files)?

Comment: @JasonDown Because I read from multiple sources, also, in the future, the user can enter even more items to the listbox

Comment: You can easily filter the source before adding, rather than adding, then removing. Just check for "color" before adding. You can even put the "adding" part into an `AddWithValidation(string line)` method and do your check there before allowing the string to be added.

Comment: @JasonDown I thought of that option since the beginning, and it doesn't work due to the larger part of the program, and it is very hard for me to explain the entire functionality of the program. In short, I must add ALL items first, then remove the unwanted one.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it. You know more about the program than i do ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ with `ListBox.Items`, but you have to cast `Items` first. Try this:

```
listBox.Items.Cast<object>()
    .Where(x => x.ToString().IndexOf("color", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => listBox.Items.Remove(x));
```

Depending on how you added items to the ListBox, you may be able to replace that with `Cast<string>()` and drop the `ToString()`.

Comment: @pasty, yes. Hence my note :). But if you add anything other than a string, then casting to `Object` and calling `ToString()` is necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I modified your code a little bit to fit my requirements, but it solved the major part of my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListBox.Items.RemoveWhere(x => ((MyType)x).stringComponent.Contains("color"));
```

or

```
ListBox.Items.ToList<MyType>().RemoveWhere(x => x.stringComponent.Contains("color"));
```

you need to tell x what type it is.

looks like you will need the remove where extension method.

```
public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        {
            if (predicate(source[i]))
            {
                source.Remove(source[i]);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. `ListBox.Items`' does not work with `RemoveWhere`.

Comment: complies for me just fine. But that is because it is an extension method in my own code base. Didnt know that.

Comment: Ah. You had an extension method hiding somewhere.